# if an error where to happen while requesting authorization to local Notifications in iOS10, what will be the authorizationStatus be?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

the code to request authorization to send local notifications in iOS 10 could be written as:

```
 UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) 
        { (success, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Request Authorization Failed (\(error), \(error.localizedDescription))")
            }
            completionHandler(success)
        }
```

I am little confused about that "error". what happens if there is an error?

will the "success:Bool" be false?
if the answer is (yes false), will that make the

```
.authorizationStatus == .denied or .notDetermined
```

Answer (score 1):

If error occurs, you will see this error in the console and *success* will be false.

From Apple documentation:

> *completionHandler*.
>
> The block to execute asynchronously with the
>   results. This block may be executed on a background thread. This block
>   has no return value and has the following parameters:
>
> **granted**.
>
> A Boolean value indicating whether authorization was granted. The value
>   of this parameter is true when authorization for the requested options
>   was granted. The value is false when authorization for one or more of
>   the options is denied.
>
> **error**.
>
> An object containing error information or
>   nil if no error occurred.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649527-requestauthorization

Comment: hi @V.Khambir, thank you for your answer. However, according to the documentation you've posted, the "granted" will be false when the user action is to deny ... but it didn't explicitly mention that if there is an error then granted will be false!! of course this could be inferred implicitly. but this still doesn't answer my original question if there is an error, then what is the .authorizationStatus value will be?